# How does electron "orbit" nucleon unless 3 coloured charges act like positive charge?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, quarks

Do quark(s) emit(s) electromagnetic wave otherwise how do(es) electron(s) form an orbital? Can colour charges somehow mimic electric charge? Btw I know quarks interact via strong nuclear force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quarks have both color charge *and* electric charge. Their electric charge is the reason they interact with electrons.

In units where a single electron has electric charge $-1$, the up quark has electric charge $+2/3$ and the down quark has electric charge $-1/3$. A proton (two ups and one down) has total electric charge $2/3 + 2/3 - 1/3 = 1$, same magnitude but opposite sign as the electron.

The color and electric charges are independent of each other in the sense that they are controlled by independent coefficients in the equations that describe the behavior of subatomic particles. Quarks have *both* kinds of charge, and electrons have only one of them (electric but not color).

Comment: may i ask do gluon exist independently?

Comment: @user6760 The gluon field is to color charge like the electromagnetic field is to electric charge. In other words, particles (like quarks) that have non-zero color charge interact with each other via the gluon field, just like particles (like both quarks and electrons) that have non-zero electric charge interact with each other via the electromagnetic field. In cases where the electromagnetic field is itself manifest as a particle, we call that particle a "photon." In cases where the gluon field is itself manifest as a particle, we call that particle a "gluon."

Comment: @user6760  One important difference between the gluon field and the electromagnetic field is that the gluon field itself (and gluons) has a non-zero color charge, so it interacts directly with itself. In contrast, the electromagnetic field (and photons) does *not* have a non-zero electric charge, so it does not interact directly with itself. The fact that the gluon field does interact directly with itself is closely related to why quarks are confined: the gluon field between two quarks tends to gather itself into a rope-like structure connecting the quarks. The electromagnetic field doesn't.

Comment: i understand so do 2 like colour charges attract each other?

Comment: @user6760 Yes: particles with color charge attract each other whether their color charges are like or unlike. This is different than how electromagnetism works, where only opposite charges attract.

Comment: So can I say the only thing keeping quarks apart is exclusion principle like electron degenercy pressure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87583/discussion-between-dan-yand-and-user6760).